# Having issue with oop and pdo in php

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I have a form on a website. This form collects data about an EVENT. The event has 20 fields besides the ID that are in the table that corresponds to the event.
Before I was just taking the ($_POST['submit']) and if true, inserting the event fields into the database using mysql_query.

Now I'm trying to use oop and this pdo and I've pretty much defeated myself at this point. I am sure I'm doing lots of things wrong.

```
<?php  
$str = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include  $str."/wp-config.php";

$config['db'] = array(
    'host'      => DB_HOST,
    'username'  => DB_USER,
    'password'  => DB_PASSWORD,
    'dbname'    => DB_NAME,
    'charset'   => DB_CHARSET
);


$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['db']['host'].';dbname='.$config['db']['dbname'].';charset='.$config['db']['charset'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDF::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


class match extends event {
    public $_matchno;
    public $_completed;

    function __construct() {
        $this->_completed = "N";
    }

    public function addMatch($matchno) {
        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_hue5gf_match_details (matchno, event_name, dateofmatch, fighttype, comp, matchref, fightclass) 
            VALUES (".$matchno.", $this->_eventname, $this->_doe, $this->_status, $this->_completed, $this->_refree, $this->_fightclass)");
        $sql->execute();
    }
}

class event {
    public $_promouser;
    public $_eventname;
    public $_fightclass;
    public $_no_of_matches;
    public $_status;
    public $_doe;
    public $_venue;
    public $_city;
    public $_state;
    public $_zip;
    public $_sanc_body;
    public $_doctor;
    public $_refree;
    public $_referee2;
    public $_judge;
    public $_judge2;
    public $_judge3;
    public $_boxcomm;
    public $_descript;

    function __construct() {
        $this->_promouser       = $_SESSION['username'];
        $this->_eventname       = $_POST['ename'];
        $this->_fightclass      = $_POST['efightclass'];
        $this->_no_of_matches   = $_POST['no_of_matches'];
        $this->_status          = $_POST['estatus'];
        $this->_doe             = $_POST['year']."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'];
        $this->_venue           = $_POST['venue'];
        $this->_city            = $_POST['city'];
        $this->_state           = $_POST['state'];
        $this->_country         = $_POST['country'];
        $this->_zip             = $_POST['zip'];
        $this->_sanc_body       = $_POST['sbody'];
        $this->_doctor          = $_POST['doctor'];
        $this->_refree          = $_POST['refree'];
        $this->_referee2        = $_POST['refree2'];
        $this->_judge           = $_POST['judge'];
        $this->_judge2          = $_POST['judge2'];
        $this->_judge3          = $_POST['judge3'];
        $this->_boxcomm         = $_POST['boxcom'];
        $this->_descript        = $_POST['descript'];
    }

    public function insertEvent() {
        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO event (promouser, eventname, fightclass, no_of_matches, status, doe, venue, city, state, country, zip, 
            sanc_body, doctor, refree, referee2, judge, judge2, judge3, boxcomm, descript) VALUES ($this->_promouser, $this->_eventname, $this->_fightclass, $this->_no_of_matches, $this->_status, $this->_venue, 
            $this->_city, $this->_state, $this->_country, $this->_zip, $this->_sanc_body, $this->_doctor, $this->_refree, $this->_referee2, $this->_judge, $this->_judge2, $this->_judge3, $this->_boxcomm, $this->_descript)");
        $sql->execute();
    }    
}
?>
```

So that is my class page. Now to the add event page. I am clearly doing something way wrong. And I have no idea where to start.

```
<?php
require_once(bloginfo( 'template_url' ).'/definedClasses.php');
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $event = new event();

    event::insertEvent();

    for($y=1;$y<= $event->_no_of_matches;$y++)
    {
        $match = new match();
        match::addMatch($y);
    }
}

?> 
 <form name="addevent" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <!-- The form here with all these inputs for the post values -->
</form>
```

I'm sure I'm trying to do too much at once. I should probably trim this down to a much smaller problem then work through it. But I have no clue where to start. I'm not looking for you to do this for me, I am looking for some guidance on what I don't understand and. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the PDO. if this was mysql_ like it used to be I have a feeling that I would have it running right.
Thanks for taking a peek.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). so your switch to PDO has gained you absolutely nothing in the way of security, other than still being usable when mysql_*() is finally removed from PHP. None of the values you're insert into the query are even quoted, so your query is undoubtedly COMPLETELY blowing up from syntax errors, even without the injection problem.

Comment: Why don't you use Prepared Statements if you're already using PDO? Your code is full of SQL injection security holes.

Comment: bindparam - I changed this stuff to make sure it wasn't me messing up on that.

$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO event (promouser, eventname, fightclass, no_of_matches, status, doe, venue, city, state, country, zip, sanc_body, doctor, refree, referee2, judge, judge2, judge3, boxcomm, descript) VALUES (:promouser, :eventname, //etc");
$sql->bindParam(':promouser', $this->promouser);
//repeat for all params
            $sql->execute();

I removed those to see what was going on and was just going back to more of a basic approach.

Comment: What errors are you getting? I see three things that I question. First, is `$db` visible within your class. I don't see any place where it's declared as global. Second, why `match::addMatch($y);` instead of `$match->addMatch($y);`? Third, use PDO `bindParam` to bind your data instead of including the variable in the SQL Prepare.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting any errors? By the the way, in your first code block you have this line of code: `$db->setAttribute(PDF::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`. You misspelled `PDO` there.

Comment: Most of my background is in javascript.  I tried writing the $db stuff in a class and that wasn't working. I'm guessing it isn't visible. I have never been able to get a proper way to debug going.  This is by far the most backwards project I have had to do but I want to do it the right way.

Comment: I don't wish to delete this, because I'm going to solve this on my own I guess.. But I'm going to go back to the drawinng board and do a lot more reading on more of the basics ofphp

Comment: @NicholasDecker Unless you are familiar with OOP I would advise you to use procedural programming just now. [**This**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is a good tutorial for PDO.

Comment: I've done limited oop in javascript and .net.  That is using code already in place and adding some smaller classes.   I really wanted to make the switch over for this site I inherited, as a way to learn, but considering the scope of the website and the headache I've had today.. I think it would be best if I started in the way I already understand and just implement PDO instead of oop and pdo..

Comment: @davidstrachan -- I went ahead and fell back to my backup copy I made yesterday (no more oop).  I have PDO implemented for a Select call, I just can't get an insert going.

Comment: @davidstrachan , it's actually quite harmful tutorial

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Code Review and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tereško -- i took the pieces I needed from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$db` in your classes because they don't know it exists.

[What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

Pass the PDO object as a parameter in your constructor

```
function __construct( PDO $db ) {
    $this->$db = $db;
}
```

Then use `$this->db` instead of `$db`

Also use `$event->insertEvent()` instead of using it statically.

A better approach would be

```
$event = new Event( $_POST );
$eventSaver = new EvenSaver( $db ); //Name is stupid but you get it
$eventSaver->saveEvent( $event );
```

but that's for a different time.